# Multiple for loops and push to array issues

Tags: arrays, for-loop

I'm probably missing something very obvious here but i'm trying to count how many "modifierSelected" per array of selected items. I would like to push the count of "modifierSelected" to an array of x and sum that up per item.

Please see my code for what i have currently.

```
  let x:any[] = [];

  let y:any = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < this.cartItems.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < this.cartItems[i].selected.length; j++) {
        y = this.cartItems[i].selected[j].modifierSelected.length;

        x.push(y);
      }

      console.log('modifiers count array', x);
  }
```

I currently see this in the console:

```
modifiers count array (2) [1, 8]
modifiers count array (4) [1, 8, 3, 2]
```

I would like to see this:

```
modifiers count array (2) [1, 8]
modifiers count array (2) [3, 2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code uses the same array twice, and thus simply adds the two onto the first array.  Try moving `let x`:

```
  let y:any = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < this.cartItems.length; i++) {

      let x:any[] = [];

      for (let j = 0; j < this.cartItems[i].selected.length; j++) {
        y = this.cartItems[i].selected[j].modifierSelected.length;

        x.push(y);
      }

      console.log('modifiers count array', x);
  }
```

Let me know if that doesn't work.

Comment: yes that's where i went wrong...so silly. thanks so much!

Comment: Common mistake :) glad to help.